# about insertRows on the Section

Tags: iphone

I have a custom a `UITableViewCell` , it has two sections.(section contain one custom cell)

that's datasource from a NSArray object.

There is another `NSArray`, I want dynamic insert these data to section.

Maybe I can not express clearly in words.

I want to achieve the same effect as instagram, I will put a picture to help you understand[image: effect like user comment]

when the user comment, section will be dynamic insert one cell.

sorry my bad English.

Thanks all.

PS: may be can user the `insertRowsAtIndexPath` method. but I dont know how use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is the right method for you.
First you need to update your array which contains the rows data (e.g: `[tableArray insertObject:newRowObject atIndex:newRowIndex];`)

After that you need to ask the table to insert those rows:

```
[tableArray insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:newRowSection], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

When you call this the tableview will insert the row(s) and will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on the datasource, where you'll provide the new row data, as you do with all your other table cells.